# Check if a matrix is square? (Python)

Tags: python, matrix

I want to test a 2x2 matrix of [[5,6],[7,8]] to see if it's a square.

I run my code and I'm supposed to get True but I got False instead...

```
 def square(sq):
     for element in sq:
         if element:
             return False
         return True
```

Comment: what is your code supposed to do?

Comment: When is a matrix square?

Comment: A 2x2 matrix is square by definition, since the number of rows equals the number of columns.

Comment: @Hyperboreus when the number of rows and the number of columns is the same

Comment: Of course not, as soon as you give it something valid with a valid element that comes before any invalid elements, it's going to return false.

Comment: It always returns `True` because your `if` statement will execute if any one `element` is not empty. Perhaps you need to rethink your program logic.

Comment: @AlexThornton Since testing if a 2x2 matrix is square is utterly pointless (since 2x2 is square by definition), perhaps OP should rethink the need for this at all!

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist maybe he just poorly phrased his question, and would like to apply it to matrix's that may not be square?

Comment: Alot of confusion going on. Sorry. Assume that (sq) is a matrix. I need to return a boolean (True) if the matrix is a square or (False) if it isn't.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to check whether a matrix is NxN, you can use:

```
def isSquare (m): return all (len (row) == len (m) for row in m)
```

As you said in your comment: if the length of all rows equals the number of rows.

Comment: Surely it would be better to store `len(m)` in a variable so you don't have to calculate it in every iteration.

Comment: @AlexThornton Is `len(m)` of a list really calculated on each call? I thought this was memoized somewhere.

Comment: Curious question, what is the benefit of doing a one line function like this versus a lambda function `isSquare = lambda m: all(len(row) == len(m) for row in m)`?

Comment: @NateMara Virtually none, but the lambda haters will flay you.

Answer (score 8):

given `m` is a `numpy` matrix and you have imported `numpy`

```
def square(m):
    return m.shape[0] == m.shape[1]
```

Comment: surely the function body should be `return m.shape[0] == m.shape[1]`

Answer (score 2):

You pass a list of lists as a parameter. The example you gave is [[5,6],[7,8]].

Let's step to see what your code does with this input.

```
for element in sq:
     if element:
         return False
     return True
```

Let's start with the for loop:

```
for element in sq:
```

This loops through your list, so the first iteration your element is [5,6] and the next [7,8].

The next thing that your code does is check if the element is True. A list is true if it's not empty. Therefore on the first iteration your code returns False.

An example input where your code would return True would be [[],[]].

To check if a matrix is square, you want to see if all the list dimensions are the same. Something along these lines:

```
def square(sq):
    rows = len(sq)
    for row in sq:
        if len(row) != rows:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

If your matrix represents two coordinates in a two dimensional space, your example is a square.  You would determine this by testing that the difference of x and y values are equal.  Code might be:

```
def square(sq):
    delta_x = sq[1][0] - sq[0][0]
    delta_y = sq[1][1] - sq[0][1]
    return delta_x == delta_y
```

Answer (score 0):

this should also work.

A is a list with matrix.

```
if not A:  
    return True  
m = len(A)  
n = len(A[0])  
if m == n:  
    return True  
else:  
    return False
```