# How to use data type in an if statement

Tags: python

I am writing a program to check if a matrix is square (The number of rows and columns are equal ex: 2x2, 3x3, etc)

I thought it would be best to count the elements using the built in size function and take the square root. I want to write an if statement where if the square root does not result in a whole number it prints an error statement, but I'm not sure how to specify a whole number in my statement.

here is what I've tried

```
    import numpy as np
    A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
    check = A.size
    if check**.5 ...
```

and I don't know what to put in the rest of the statement

Comment: To check if a value is a whole number, you can use `x % 1 == 0`, but this approach will fail for checking for square arrays. For example, a matrix of size `(18, 2)` will return `True` if you check that the square root of its size is an integer.

Comment: Taking the square root of the size is needlessly complex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a matrix is square? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870734/check-if-a-matrix-is-square-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `shape` attribute is probably what you want to check.

```py
if A.shape[0] == A.shape[1]:
    # Is square
else:
    # Is not square
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if it's an integer.

```
if check**.5 == int(check**.5):
    ...
```

Comment: This is a bad idea in general; for certain large near-squares, this check will return true due to floating-point precision issues.

Comment: Granted, the best solution to the problem is provided to Jmonsky. Although I often feel that SO answers questions that weren't asked. OP wanted to know how to check if it's a whole number.

Comment: And like I said, this is not a good way to do that, because floating-point values have limited precision. Consider `x = 99999999; y = ((x+1)*(x-1))**.5`. `x**2 != (x+1)*(x-1)`, but `y == int(y)`.

Comment: I fold, if OP constructs a 99999999x99999999 dimensional matrix this solution will not work.

Comment: I didn't downvote because in the context of the question, it's *probably* OK, but I wouldn't rule out the existence of smaller, less-square matrices that give the same false positive.